# How to enable management console in rabitmq on windows?

Tags: java, windows, rabbitmq

I've installed rabitMq, wrote simple application and I want to watch managent console.

I've encountered that I can't do this.

I opened [folowing page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

and read:

The management plugin is included in the RabbitMQ distribution. To enable it, use rabbitmq-plugins:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

The Web UI is located at: http://server-name:15672/

Where should I write this command?

I use windows and rabitmq was run as service:

[image]

My server locates by the path

```
 C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.10
```

How can I see management plugin?

Answer (score 2):

command

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

works from folder

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.10\sbin
```

from `cmd`